# What is the substitute of this specific "if condition with a this pointer"?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
if(strcmp(un,this->username)==0 && strcmp(pw,this->password)==0)
```

Could anyone of you please instruct me the significance of "this" function? Also, what could be a possible alternative of it?

Comment: I think this question needs. a little more contexts on what other variables are available to this if statement and if the compiler needs the programmer to clarify if there is more that one choice for `username` and `password`

Answer (score 1):

It's only necessary if you need to distinguish the member variable `username` from one that's local to the function that contains your `if` statement.

The same applies to `password`.

If neither apply then you can write

```
if (!strcmp(un, username) && !strcmp(pw, password))
```

By the way, using a contiguous character array to store a password is not particularly secure. You wouldn't see code like this in a professional context.